# Gulp globbing excluding files then unexcluding not working as described

Tags: gulp, gulp-glob

If I have the files

```
client/
  a.js
  bob.js
  bad.js
```

And the gulp task

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(['client/*.js', '!client/b*.js', 'client/bad.js'])
             .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

then according to the [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) we should copy `a.js` and `bad.js`. However, when I run this with gulp v3.9.1, it only copies `a.js`.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, the documentation is just wrong. The newest version of gulp is `gulp@3.9.1` which uses `vinyl-fs@0.3.14`. The [behavior you're referring to](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/commit/558f3744489d5e671f4172453b24ba62bfd9b102) wasn't introduced until `vinyl-fs@1.0.0`.

In fact, elsewhere the gulp docs [explicitly state](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/CHANGELOG.md#vinylvinyl-fs-changes) that glob ordering will be a new feature in `gulp@4.0.0`:

> globs passed to gulp.src will be evaluated in order, which means this is possible `gulp.src(['*.js', '!b*.js', 'bad.js'])` (exclude every JS file that starts with a `b` except bad.js)

That means you could simply use to the current development version of gulp (`gulpjs/gulp#4.0`) and take advantage of the new feature. Note however that gulp 4.x is [radically different](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/) from gulp 3.x when it comes to defining tasks.

One workaround would be to keep using gulp 3.x for tasks definitions, but use the newest version of `vinyl-fs` to create vinyl streams:

```
var vinylFs = require('vinyl-fs');

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return vinylFs.src(['client/*.js', '!client/b*.js', 'client/bad.js'])
    .pipe(vinylFs.dest('public'));
});
```

And if you don't want to do that you can always use [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) to combine multiple streams into one stream:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return merge(gulp.src(['client/*.js', '!client/b*.js']),
               gulp.src(['client/bad.js']))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like another solution, the one I ended up using, was to use [https://github.com/UltCombo/gulp-src-ordered-globs/](gulp-src-ordered-globs). This acts as a drop-in replacement for `gulp.src` with the expected glob behavior.